# Flutter change slider thumb to image

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, dart-null-safety

I want to create something like this.

[image]

I have managed to create it but anytime I start the app, I get **LateInitializationError** which says `LateInitializationError: Field 'customImage' has not been initialized.`  before the slider shows.

This is my code. What am I doing wrong? I also tried the flutter xlider package but it doesn't work anymore since it doesn't support null safety. If you have a better way of changing the slider thumb, it will be greatly appreciated.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class CustomSlider extends StatefulWidget {
  const CustomSlider({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CustomSliderState createState() => _CustomSliderState();
}

class _CustomSliderState extends State<CustomSlider> {
  late ui.Image customImage;
  double sliderValue = 0.0;

  Future<ui.Image> loadImage(String assetPath) async {
    ByteData data = await rootBundle.load(assetPath);
    ui.Codec codec = await ui.instantiateImageCodec(data.buffer.asUint8List());
    ui.FrameInfo fi = await codec.getNextFrame();

    return fi.image;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    loadImage('images/star.png').then((image) {
      setState(() {
        customImage = image;
      });
    });

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SliderTheme(
      data: SliderThemeData(
        trackHeight: 28,
        inactiveTrackColor: Colors.grey.shade300,
        activeTrackColor: const Color(0xFFFFE900),
        thumbShape: SliderThumbImage(customImage),
      ),
      child: Slider(
        value: 50,
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        onChanged: (value) {},
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SliderThumbImage extends SliderComponentShape {
  final ui.Image image;

  SliderThumbImage(this.image);

  @override
  Size getPreferredSize(bool isEnabled, bool isDiscrete) {
    return const Size(0, 0);
  }

  @override
  void paint(PaintingContext context, Offset center,
      {required Animation<double> activationAnimation,
      required Animation<double> enableAnimation,
      required bool isDiscrete,
      required TextPainter labelPainter,
      required RenderBox parentBox,
      required SliderThemeData sliderTheme,
      required TextDirection textDirection,
      required double value,
      required double textScaleFactor,
      required Size sizeWithOverflow}) {
    final canvas = context.canvas;
    final imageWidth = image.width;
    final imageHeight = image.height;

    Offset imageOffset = Offset(
      center.dx - (imageWidth / 2),
      center.dy - (imageHeight / 2),
    );

    Paint paint = Paint()..filterQuality = FilterQuality.high;

    canvas.drawImage(image, imageOffset, paint);
  }
}
```

Comment: you need `ui.Image? customImage;` not `late ui.Image customImage;` and inside `SliderThumbImage` you should check if `image` is not `null` before drawing it

Comment: I tried that but I am getting Null check operator used on a null value error.

Comment: this is because you should check if `image` is not `null` before using it

Comment: check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/73872457/2126077

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`initState` runs before the widget is built, but can't be an async function, so `customImage = image;` will almost surely run later than the `build` function. And since you are using `customImage` in the `build` function, and `customImage` is marked as late, you receive this error.

You can remove `late` keyword, make `customImage` nullable, and in the `build` method check for its value. If it is null (image not loaded yet), display a progress indicator for example.

But this is not perfect, because depending on the time that image loading takes, there is a chance that `setState` is invoked while the widget is being built, which would trigger another error.

Although you can solve the above with an `addPostFrameCallback`, the best way is to use a `FutureBuilder`, load the image first and build your widget afterwards:

```
late Future<ui.Image> _loadImage;

@override
void initState() 
  super.initState();
  _loadImage = loadImage();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return FutureBuilder<ui.Image>(
      future: _loadImage,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData || snapshot.data != null) {
          return SliderTheme(
            data: SliderThemeData(
              trackHeight: 28,
              inactiveTrackColor: Colors.grey.shade300,
              activeTrackColor: const Color(0xFFFFE900),
              thumbShape: SliderThumbImage(snapshot.data!),
            ),
            child: Slider(
              value: 50,
              min: 0,
              max: 100,
              onChanged: (value) {},
            ),
          );
        }
        // progress indicator while loading image,
        // you can return and empty Container etc. if you like
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
      });
}
```

Comment: Good to hear, you are welcome. In most cases it is a good idea to avoid calling `async` functions in `initState`.

Answer (score 0):

All non-late variables are initialized to null. If a variable is non-nullable, it would be an error if this ever contained null, so this is a compile time error:

```
int? number;  // initialized to null
var  str;  // compile-time error
```

Make your field nullable

```
  ui.Image? customImage;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried making it nullable and I am getting this error: Null check operator used on a null value