# How can I build the following thumb for a slider?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

[image]

I tried making a class that extends from SliderComponentShape, but canvas.drawImage doesn't work for me since I have to pass a custom color for the border of the thumb

```
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class SliderThumbImage extends SliderComponentShape {
  final ui.Image image;
  final BuildContext buildContext;

  SliderThumbImage(this.image, this.buildContext);

  @override
  Size getPreferredSize(bool isEnabled, bool isDiscrete) {
      return Size(0, 0);
  }
  
  @override
  void paint(PaintingContext context, ui.Offset center, {required Animation<double> activationAnimation, required Animation<double> enableAnimation, required bool isDiscrete, required TextPainter labelPainter, required RenderBox parentBox, required SliderThemeData sliderTheme, required ui.TextDirection textDirection, required double value, required double textScaleFactor, required ui.Size sizeWithOverflow}) {
    final canvas = context.canvas;
    final imageWidth = image.width;
    final imageHeight = image.height;

    Offset imageOffset = Offset(center.dx - (imageWidth / 2) , center.dy - (imageHeight / 2));

    Paint paint = Paint()..filterQuality = FilterQuality.high;

    canvas.drawImage(image, imageOffset, paint);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [dart_image_slider](https://pub.dev/packages/dart_image_slider/example)

```
Slider _getSlider() {
return Slider(
  value: _currentValue,
  max: 100,
  divisions: 10,
  label: _currentValue.round().toString(),
  onChanged: (double value) {
    setState(() {
      _currentValue = value;
    });
  },
);
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text(widget.title),
    ),
    body: DartImageSlider(
      slider: _getSlider(),
      imagePath: 'assets/button.png',
    ));
}
```

If you wish , you can have the source code [here](https://github.com/HeshanSandeepa/dart_image_slider)